# Sitecore - Do stuff when media item saved

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

I want to run some custom code when a media item is saved, but there doesn't seem to be a media item save pipeline. We aren't trying to change the item in anyway what so ever - we just want to run some custom code when a media item gets saved. Google mentioned the Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider but I read that this cannot be overridden. Does anyone know of a pipeline or custom processor we can override that is fired when a media item is saved?

I am running Sitecore 6.5 rev 120706.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A MediaItem inherits from a CustomItemBase class. The CustomItemBase class also uses the item:saved event so you can create a custom event to handle your custom code.

A quick way to check if you are dealing with a mediaItem:

```
if (myItem.Paths.IsMediaItem)
{
  // your custom code
}
```

Comment: perfect, for any one interested see this blog post http://gettingtoknowsitecore.blogspot.co.nz/